# Markdown's URL parsing does not properly handle unicode

Tags: bug, unicode

[At some point in the past](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/254/3035), unicode symbols such as Japanese kana became supported in Stack Exchange question URLs.

However, in comments and posts, when pasting a link using these symbols, they are truncated. For example, the following URL:

```
https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2102/what-is-the-こと-in-sentences-suc‌​h-as-あなたのことが好きだ
```

... is the correct URL for the question with ID 2102. However, the following code does not create a link:

```
[Link title](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2102/what-is-the-こと-in-sentences-suc‌​h-as-あなたのことが好きだ)
```

... and, if you just paste the link itself without the `[]()` Markdown, you get this (hover over it to see the actual link URL):

> [What is the こと in sentences such as あなたのことが好きだ?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2102/what-is-the-%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8-in-sentences-suc)‌​h-as-あなたのことが好きだ

... which produces the following (in case this post fixes itself):

[image: Link parsing cuts off at symbol こ, and presumably other Japanese symbols]

Can we get link parsing support for these unicode characters in Markdown `[]()` and auto-linking syntax?

Comment: When I hover over I see japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2102/what-is-the but it redirects correctly because the ID is valid.

Comment: @Tim Yes, but *only* because the ID is valid. (The title is not needed at all, but when it's provided, it should parse.)

Comment: I'm not sure it does parse, I noticed that when I pasted in a question with long question title, it got it correct - even though the title was cut off.

Comment: @Tim I don't know what you mean. The issue here is that the URL provided is a valid URL which isn't properly recognized as Markdown starting at the first Unicode character.

Comment: Ahh, okay don't worry then.